# Defining functions composed of partial functions

Tags: functions, notation, definition

Suppose f and g are partial functions from integers to integers. I want to define other functions in terms of f and g, for example:

p(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)

Now if f(x) and f(y) are defined then p(x,y) is too. But what if f(x) is defined but g(y) is not? What I want is that p(x,y) is then also undefined. But can I take it as given that "f(x) + undefined" equals undefined? Or should I define different cases to handle this?

A similar problem arises with a function such as

q(x,y,z) = min(f(z) + x, g(z) + y).

Can I take it as given that min(n, undefined) is undefined?

Of course there is also

r(x) = f(g(x))

where I guess it's super obvious that r(x) is undefined if g(x) is undefined. But even on this I can't find any definite advice in the text books.

So my question is mostly about how to present my definitions. Do I have to consider each case of undefined terms separately? I hope not because that would seriously clutter up the text that I'm writing.

Comment: In any expression, if one or more sub-expressions is undefined, the expression is undefined. As you said, it's "super obvious". The discussion would typically be found in precalcus books where the domains of sums, differences, products, quotients, composites are analyized.

Comment: Thus, the domain of a sum is the intersection of the domains. Same for differences and products. For quotients, you also need to exclude points which would make the denominator zero. Composites are a little trickier.

Comment: Just take $\text{dom}(p)=\text{dom}(f)\times \text{dom}(g)$.